# How can I force user to enter emoji only in edittext

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, emoji

I'm using androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiEditText. I want to force user to enter only emojis here. And limit him to max 3 emojis. How can I do something like this? I tried to use external emoji keyboard that cancels the soft keyboard and shows up but didn't work properly.

```
<androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiEditText
                            android:id="@+id/etEmoji"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:hint="Enter Emoji"
                            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Comment: I think you need to create custom editText which only allow  Character.SURROGATE and Character.OTHER_SYMBOL and you can add android:maxLength="3" to limit emoji length

Comment: @Nik android:maxLength. Counts the emojis as chars not every emojis as one entry. Some emojis takes 2 chars and other takes 3. So I can't put a fixed number here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below class will only allow Emojis and symbols.

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {
        public CustomEditText(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init();
        }

        public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init();
        }

        public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new EmojiIncludeFilter()});
        }

        private class EmojiIncludeFilter implements InputFilter {

            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                    int type = Character.getType(source.charAt(i));
                    if (type != Character.SURROGATE && type != Character.OTHER_SYMBOL) {
                        // Other then emoji value will be blank
                        return "";
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: will it work with androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiEditText?

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks. How can I add a condition here to limit emojis to 3 max? My problem with android:maxLength is some emojis takes more than 2 chars so I'm not able to fixed number here. It counts chars not the whole emoji as one entry.

Comment: @Blackmamba I tried it. It works with no issues. Just extend it from EmojiEditText instead of EditText

Comment: This won't work for all of the emojis;
For example the ☂ (umbrella) emoji is filtered out is this case